# What is a good method to test the effect of gibberellin concentration?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

I was just wondering what a good method would be to test the effect of gibberellin concentration on growth. I know it is prevelant in many flowering plants but am unsure as to what would be suitable. I have been looking into tepary beans as one but am unsure as to how exactly I would measure 'growth'/the effect of gibberellin.

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, the 'good' plant would depend on _how_ you measure the effect of gibberellin. I think you should change the wording of the question from _good plant_ to _good method_.

Comment: Gibberellins cause elongation - the acids were discovered by study of rice bolting in Japan. Fundamentally measure stem elongation versus concentration of applied GAx. There would remain a question of how effectively the GAx was adsorbed that would require some further chemical analysis - of xylem water if applied as a root drench, for example.

Comment: Could you possibly direct on me on how to apply the gibberellin as I have not found a simple methodology for this. I have also read in a number of papers that it also effects root length, germination period etc. Would it also be possible to explore these? How would I also go about applying it as a root drench?

Comment: Exogenous GA can be adsorbed via foliar sprays but more usually as a root drench. With bare rooted plants, you could prune all to the same root length, dip the roots in the solution for a period of time, then pot them. Afterward bare root the plants and measure root length. With potted plants or 'planted' plants, just pour an amount of solution on the soil.at the base of each plant (no ability to measure root length in this case). With seeds see http://www.jlhudsonseeds.net/GibberellicAcid.htm